# macOS Catalina and /usr/include no longer existing. Build problems using gcc, gcc-10 and clang

Tags: macos, gcc, clang, macos-catalina

Since the latest update of Xcode 12 on my recently upgraded MacBook from Mojave to Catalina, I can no longer build my project that uses an old MakeFile. I've tried setting SDKROOT env var and added -isysroot  to the old MakeFile but still I get the error:

```
gcc -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -ggdb  -w -DREAL_8 -DINTEGER_IS_INT -DLITTLE_ENDIAN     -DTABLE_PATH=\"/usr/lib/\" -c PBGroutines.c
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/include/stdio.h', needed by `extras.o'.  Stop.
```

I've tried using gcc:

```
gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

also gcc-10 installed through HomeBrew:

```
gcc-10 -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc-10
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin19/10.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19
Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin19 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/lib/gcc/10 --disable-nls --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --program-suffix=-10 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl --with-system-zlib --with-pkgversion='Homebrew GCC 10.2.0' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues --disable-multilib --with-native-system-header-dir=/usr/include --with-sysroot=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk SED=/usr/bin/sed
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 10.2.0 (Homebrew GCC 10.2.0)
```

and finally clang:

```
clang -v
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

but all fail with the same error. I'm running out of ideas after searching extensively.

commandline-tools are installed as noted by `xcode-select --install` and stdio.h is located in the SDK. What am I missing?

**EDIT**
Just now noticed that the line before the error refers to `PBGroutines.c` while the error relates to `extras.o`. Hence, the problem seems with linking. Also running just the gcc command (with or without) `-isysroot` runs fine. So how can I do something similar for the linking step?

**EDIT 2**
So I have found the problem. Apparently this library MakeFile includes the following line:

```
include make.dep
```

The content of `make.dep` contains dependencies with are hardcoded:

```
#
# Header file dependencies
#
PBGroutines.o: PBGroutines.h
crexrd.o: /usr/include/stdio.h
extras.o: /usr/include/stdio.h
```

Removing the `include make.dep` from the MakeFile fixes compilation but I am not sure if this is wanted behaviour? Is it better to create another make.dep with dynamically created file locations? What does this make.dep actually do?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can try specify path to your SDK with `-isysroot`

Comment: @Olha I've improved my question to clearly indicate that I already tried that and still got the error.